# How to pass concatenated list as argument?

Tags: python

I try to pass a list of parameters to a function that has to be put together from lists and dictionaries, but as usual, Python is unhelpfully whining about something being "not iterable" or "not subscriptable" without telling what exactly is wrong. Consider the following:

```
argl=[p,T,C]
argl.append(list(ph.items))      
Ci['ol']=fsolve(Cr_impl,0.1*C,argl)
```

where `fsolve` is the root-finder from numpy and ph is a dictionary with entries of the form `'ol': 0.55` etc. and `p`, `T`, and `C` are simple scalars containing some real numbers. Python whines that the `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`. I also tried

```
argl=[p,T,C]+list(ph.items)
```

with the same result, as well as

```
argl=[p,T,C]+ph.items
```

which results in

```
can only concatenate list (not "builtin_function_or_method") to list
```

So, what does it want? There must be way to take apart the dict in such a way that it can be merged into a longer list (which can then be rearranged in the called function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict.items` is a method. You need to add parentheses to it to actually call it. e.g.

```
argl.append(list(ph.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is `ph.items` returns as built-in method generator and `ph.items()` return your desired list of values.

Corrects the code as `argl.append(list(ph.items()))`

Answer (score 0):

Although already answered by others, the following might give you some more idea:

```
dic={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
print (dic.keys)
```

Output
    `<built-in method keys of dict object ....`

```
print (dic.keys())
```

Output `dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])`

The same applies to the `dic.values`. Hope you got your answer.